# Grab only one out of several node labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

if I have a node with more than one label - how can I receive a selected label of that collection, lets say only the 2nd or 3rd?

The node schema is (g:Group:Group1:Group2)

I can grab the first maybe with

```
MATCH (g:Group) WHERE LENGTH(LABELS(g)) = 1 return labels(g);
```

When I raise the length up to 2 I get the first and the second label [Group, Group1] - but I would want only to have the label [Group1]. Is it possible to select individual labels out of the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can reference individual labels out of the collection. Consider the following example.  Find nodes with the `Group` label that have three labels each and return the last label in the collection.

```
match (g:Group)
where length(labels(g)) = 3
return labels(g)[2];
```